# Sort_link with Ransack for format mm-yyyy in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I use Ransack for filtering and sorting my tables.
One of my models has a column named "billing_period".
This period is stored in my database as characters in the format mm-yyyy.
So for this month I have "12-2019".

For sorting the table on the billing_periods I have:

```
= sort_link(@q, :billing_period)
```

Ransack only sorts it on the first two characters, the months.
Like this:

01-2018

01-2019

02-2018

02-2019

How I can include the years in the sorting?
What I want to see is:

01-2018

02-2018

etc.

Comment: are you having 'string' datatype for 'billing_period'?

Comment: Yes I have. It's a string.

Comment: This is the reason You are getting sorting like this.

Comment: You need to take 'billing_period' as 'datetime' and it will work perfactly fine as you want.